# Android Button Is Not Changing Image To Fit Inside

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, scaletype

I am programatically creating a button. However no matter what I set the button icon is appearing outside the bounds of the box. I want the image to to fit inside the button dimensions. Change my scale type has no effect (CENTER_CROP looks the same as FIT_CENTER) so likely theres something fundamentally wrong with my code. If you can suggest what I am doing wrong I'd appreciate it:

```
    int buttonDimension = 100;

    _cancelSelectPhotoButton = new ImageButton(this);
    _cancelSelectPhotoButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.deselecticon);
    _cancelSelectPhotoButton.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    _cancelSelectPhotoButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);//all scale types look the same
    _cancelSelectPhotoButton.setAdjustViewBounds(false);//true has no effect either
    _cancelSelectPhotoButton.setMinimumHeight(buttonDimension);
    _cancelSelectPhotoButton.setMaxHeight(buttonDimension);
    _cancelSelectPhotoButton.setMinimumWidth(buttonDimension);
    _cancelSelectPhotoButton.setMaxWidth(buttonDimension);
    _cancelSelectPhotoButton.setX(0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it and the following combination worked for me:

```
 _cancelSelectPhotoButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
 _cancelSelectPhotoButton.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

This is what i'm getting. I added a background color to the ImageButton and a padding in order to see the actual box.

[image]

**NOTE:**

After testing with different approaches, we found out that if you set a background color to the ImageButton, the image fits correctly.
Without it, somehow works on Nexus 5 but not on Nexus 6.

```
_cancelSelectPhotoButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: And it still doesnt work for me...hmmm. I dont have any other references to this object either.

Comment: I tested it using a 144x144 image with buttonDimension set to 50. I added it directly on a RelativeLayout without any other view.

Comment: I too have a relative layout. Is your image WITHIN the background box?

Comment: I added an image of what I get

Comment: Yes, it is. The only difference i see is that your using a round icon and i am using a square one. I will add an image of what i'm getting

Comment: Well curious because as you can see in my image using the same code as you my background is smaller than the width and height of the texture

Comment: Ok, this is really weird, i just tried with a round image and it is still placing it inside the box. I'm compiling on Lollipop 5.1.. which Android version are you using?

Comment: That is my exact image file, want to give that a try too?

Comment: Mine only fits in the box if I use .setPadding(20,20,20,20) otherwise I get the above. This is only making me pull my hair out more hahaha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77926/discussion-between-mmark-and-aggressor).